# Foxit - How many pages in a pdf document?

Tags: document-management

When I open a pdf in Foxit, I should be able to see, instantly, the total number of pages in the document. Why can't I?

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions, the status bar is auto-hide. To make it permanently visible, right-click in a blank spot on the toolbar, go down to the statusbar entry and change it to SHOW.